# How to restrict Custom Elements from accessing other dom elements?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I need to segregate custom elements from the rest of the page in terms of access ..

**My html :**

```
<html>
<script src="helloelement.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="normal">normal element</div>
<hello-element name="Everyone"></hello-element>
</body>
</html>
```

**helloelement.js:**

```
class HelloElement extends HTMLElement {
  // Monitor the 'name' attribute for changes.
  static get observedAttributes() {return ['name']; }

  // Respond to attribute changes.
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (attr == 'name') {
      this.textContent = `Hello, ${newValue}`;

      alert(document.getElementById("normal").innerHTML="from custom");
    }
  }
}

// Define the new element
customElements.define('hello-element', HelloElement);
```

In this line ,

```
  alert(document.getElementById("normal").innerHTML="from custom");
```

it access and modifies other element "normal".. Can i restrict it to access only that are present inside custom elements ?

eg: only those that are inside hello-element should be accessible inside helloelement.js ..

Any reference ?
**Thanks !**

Comment: if it's you who defnes the content of the custom element what is the problem ? You can test a condition to check if it's inside the element, no?

Comment: if this element is embedded in some page it should not access the document other than itself.but in my js script if i put document.body.innerHTML="something" it will change the entire page in which it is embedded right ?
Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: yes you're right, you cannot avoid that. you must trust the web components you insert in your page

Answer (score 0):

A web component is written using JavaScript and there is no sandboxing limitations to what that JavaScript does.

You either need to write your own components so you can establish your own rules, trust third party components, or only use trusted components that your team/system has vetted.

Comment: So if I want to replace iframes with web components(shadow DOM (read recently))I cant achieve  it?

Comment: You can.  But there is always the risk of a component not playing by the rules of your team didn't write it. If your tram is in control or reviews all components then you should be fine.  Shadow DOM isn't really a help for protection, just encapsulation.

Comment: So kind of custom rules should be imposed on widgets(/code that creates it) created .(that are not loaded in iframe).

Comment: This answers my question of if javascript in a Shadow DOM can modify the parent document... it can. I was wondering if I could put theming widgets into Shadow DOM custom elements, and when the user interacts, how to feed that back to theme the parent document... just have the element tweak the parent document classes or CSS, is the answer. So while I understand a desire for protection, if it is ever implemented, it should be an option, or have configurable escape routes.